# Don't know how to print a dictionary which has a list inside

Tags: c#

This is the input I'm using for the current case:

```
Like Krisi shrimps
Like Krisi soup
Like Penelope dessert
Like Misho salad
stop
```

This is my whole code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace GuestsFoods._1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            //input:
            //Like Krisi shrimps
            //Like Krisi soup
            //Like Penelope dessert
            //Like Misho salad
            //stop
            int unliked = 0;
            Dictionary<string, List<string>> guestsFoods = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>(); 
            // Key: Krisi, Value: shrimps, soup 
            // Key: Penelope, Value: dessert
            // Key: Misho , Value: salad
            while(input != "stop")
            {
                List<string> inputs = input.Split(" ").ToList();
                if (inputs[0] == "Like")
                {
                    if (guestsFoods.ContainsKey(inputs[1]))
                    {
                        guestsFoods[inputs[1]].Add(inputs[2]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        guestsFoods.Add(inputs[1], new List<string> {inputs[2]});
                    }

                }
                else if (inputs[0] == "Dislike")
                {
                    if (guestsFoods!.ContainsKey(inputs[1]))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{inputs[1]} is not at the party");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        guestsFoods[inputs[1]].Remove(inputs[2]);
                        unliked++;
                    }
                }
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            //foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> data in guestsFoods)
            //{
                //Console.WriteLine(data.Key + " -> ");
                //foreach (string food in guestsFoods[new List<string>[]])
                //{
                    //Console.Write("");
                //}
            //}
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I am using the Dictionary.Key to store the person's name and the Dictionary.Value, which is a list, to store the foods they like.
I want my output to be printed like this:

```
Key - Value1, Value2, Value3 ... ValueN
```

But I don't know how to do it. As you can see by the comments I tried to do it myself, but I can't think of the logic required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your (commented out) loop, if `data.Key` is the `string` for the dictionary entry, then `data.Value` is the `List<string>`.  You can loop over that list:

```
foreach (string val in data.Value)
{
    Console.Write(val);
}
```

Maybe add some formatting:

```
foreach (string val in data.Value)
{
    Console.Write($"{val}, ");
}
```

Which you'll then find leaves you with a trailing comma.  You can add logic to *conditionally* show the comma.  But fortunately we don't need to go down this road, because `string.Join` makes this even easier.  In fact, you don't need a loop at all once you use that:

```
Console.Write(string.Join(", ", data.Value));
```

Which would combine all the strings in the list with `", "` as a delimiter.